# sql round function throw error - Schema "pg_catalog" does not exist

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, vertica

I'm querying Vertica using `node-vertica` npm packge (Node server), I noticed that every time the `ROUND` expression is **0/null**, I'm getting the error - `ERROR: Schema "pg_catalog" does not exist`.

**EDIT:**

For example:

```sql
SELECT 
  name,
  email,
  ROUND(SUM(grade)/nullifzero(count(grade))) as avrage ----> ROUND(0/null)
FROM il_grades
GROUP BY name,email
LIMIT 10
```

Return this error. Once I remove the ROUND() - everything is working properly.

Comment: Must be a Vertica issue, it works on community Postgres: `select round(0/null); NULL`. I would suggest contacting Vertica support.

Comment: `Avg #` is not valid as a column name, you need to put it in quotes `"Avg #"`. Also doesn't make much sense to have aggregations with non-aggregated columns and no `group by`, nor the `limit`. Perhaps you are missing some code, or you want window functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertica-client package was the issue (unmaintained) , after I removed it and install the official Vertica's `vertica-nodejs` node pkg it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Now, I don't run into your error.
Well, it's standard Vertica as it runs everywhere, on Linux from an  RPM, on AWS, on GCP, on Azure ...

with `grade` with int values 0 through 8:

```
WITH
il_grades(id,name,email,grade) AS (
            SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',0
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',2 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',3 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',4 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',5 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',6 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',7 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',8 
)
SELECT 
  name,
  email,
  ROUND(SUM(grade)/nullifzero(count(grade))) as avrage ----> ROUND(0/null)
FROM il_grades
GROUP BY name,email
LIMIT 10
;
 name |    email    |        avrage        
------+-------------+----------------------
 Joe  | joe@foo.com | 4.000000000000000000
```

With `grade` set to NULL everywhere:

```
WITH
il_grades(id,name,email,grade) AS (
            SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',NULL::INT 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',NULL::INT 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',NULL::INT 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',NULL::INT 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',NULL::INT 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',NULL::INT 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',NULL::INT 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',NULL::INT 
  UNION ALL SELECT 42,'Joe','joe@foo.com',NULL::INT 
)
SELECT 
  name,
  email,
  ROUND(SUM(grade)/nullifzero(count(grade))) as avrage ----> ROUND(0/null)
FROM il_grades
GROUP BY name,email
LIMIT 10
;
 name |    email    | avrage 
------+-------------+--------
 Joe  | joe@foo.com | (null)
(1 row)
```